# Should you omit empty fields in an API?

Tags: json, api

This might be a really simple question but I can't seem to find a definitive answer. I want to know from a API best practice point of view, should you send over empty fields (empty string or null) or should you omit them from the API altogether?

I've looked at other APIs and I can see empty fields being sent over. Also, to me sending over empty field also shows the consumer what is available in the API, but on the flip side it's extra data for no reason.

Anyone know if there's a correct answer/best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this would be considered best practice by all, but from my experience the best option is you only require the client to send the data they need to. So if you have fields that can be blank or null then they don't need to be sent by the requester.

Comment: From a GET point of view I was thinking the API becomes self documenting if you include all fields available, even though they may not be present for that particular entry. I can definitely see 2 side to the argument, that's why I thought it would be good to see what others thought.

Comment: Hmm... ok, when you send the data back it depends on your application, if it's a table-like concept then yes, send all the fields, but if it's more object-like then maybe not. Also it depends how complex your schema is. I would say though no API is ever really self-documenting. Even if all the fields are returned you need to outline data types/validation. API documentation is definitely best practice.

Comment: @ChrisPowell thanks. I think we'll go for the omit approach then. All the field details are in the documentation, so your approach makes sense.